# Can a SQL query join to tables that aren't known under execution time?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a query that is going to extract a huge amount of data from a system on a regular basis.

The problem I have is there are ~100 tables that have gibberish names that are created by the application as new projects are started.  The name of the table for a specific project is held in the project table.

So I need to join between the project table, a handful of others, then each of the tables listed in a column from the project table.

Is this possible, if so any pointers?

Comment: "any pointers?" - how about jobserve.com ;-)

Comment: More seriously, you will need to look into "dynamic SQL"

Comment: News flash... your application is moronic! Instead of creating a new table for each project, how about using the *same* table with an extra column called `project_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Put your query into `EXECUCTE IMMEDIATE` statement. (this is called dynamic sql)

```
declare
  vcTableName varchar2(30);
  vcResult varchar2(128);
begin

  vcTableName := 'SOME_TABLE_NAME';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT column FROM '||vcTableName||' WHERE conditions' into vcResult;

  do_something(vcResult);

end;
/
```